# Chrome and Skype takes up a lot of storage

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, chrome-for-android, skype

I'm not sure if this is a problem different for anyone but these apps are very large.

I'm on a very limited storage of 2Gb with no move to sd capabilities and both these apps rise above 150Mb in space.

Updating both apps is simply impossible because I would have to remove a lot of apps to do so.
I'd rater rather just delete both but I actively use both and Chrome is the default browser.
Also Skype had issues with the latest version so I was forced to downgrade.

And before answers arise saying just delete the data. That includes preferences, logins and bookmarks.

For extra info:

Phone: Sony Xperia M / C1905 rooted

OS version: 4.3

Build: 15.4.A.1.9

Chrome: 41.0.2272.96 (outdated)

Skype: 5.3.0.65246 (outdated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how you have problems if your device only has 2Gb of storage.

The size of the apps are determined by two factors: app size and data/cache size. The app size is the size of the app code and its data. How much space this takes up is determined by the developer.

Data is the actual app data and cache consists of temporary files that can be deleted any time. Clearing your cache will not delete user accounts or settings. Clearing data can.

If the 'data' part of the apps is taking too much space, you should enable Chrome sync. This will sync all history/bookmarks and some settings across your devices, so if you clear the data after syncing your data will appear again after logging in again.

This does not solve the problem of storage shortage, it will only delay it. You have root, and [this page](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_m-5497.php) says you can insert a MicroSD card into your phone so Link2SD might be an option.

If you have an external SD card about 4GB+, you can easily extend the amount of storage your apps can use by using an app like [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD).
Link2SD (and similar apps) allow you to reserve some part of your SD-card for app storage by allow you to use an ext2/ext4 partition as data storage. You can follow any tutorial like [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1432459) or [this one](http://rootmyandroid.org/how-to-use-link2sd-tutorial-guide.html/) to set it up. You don't have an HTC device so you can ignore the S-OFF stuff. Most tutorials will guide you every step, but it all comes down to this:

1. Always make backups of everything just to be sure
2. Install [Minitool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html) and insert your SD-card into your computer
3. Resize the existing FAT32 partition of your SD-card to create some space for apps
4. Create a new *primary*, ext2 partition in the free space (some tutorials use ext4 but ext4 is less fit for solid state storage like SD-cards)
5. Install [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) and select the new partition when you are to select one

Keep in mind that the ext2 partition will be reserved and no non-app files can be stored in the reserved space (like photos, music, videos). Also, any apps on the SD-card will be gone if you boot your device without an SD-card. If you have a cheap/bad SD-card apps will be a lot slower than when they ran from the internal storage. Use class 8 or higher SD-card for the best results.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do anything about those two monsters using so much data – they're known for that. But still, there's something to work around that, enabling you to "update" without losing your data:

1. Backup for safety (data only)

   ```
   adb backup -noapk -f Skype.ab com.raider.skype
   adb backup -noapk -f Chrome.ab com.android.chrome
   ```
2. Remove the apps, but keep their data

   ```
   adb uninstall -k com.raider.skype
   adb uninstall -k com.android.chrome
   ```
3. Install the apps anew using e.g. the Playstore app

If that doesn't work out (as the amount of data still is too much), ommit the `-k` in the second step – and to restore your data, follow the third step by

```
adb restore Skype.ab
adb restore Chrome.ab
```

This requires your computer to be equipped with [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) (see the [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for details, including a minimal install as you won't need the entire SDK for that).

Comment: Why did you choose `ADB` over TiBa when the device is rooted?

Comment: @Firelord With the OP's device already low on space and not able to update several apps, I chose an approach not involving the install of additional apps. Of course it would work with TiBu as well – but that might have lead to ping-pong ("cannot install, not enough storage free, what now?"). The ADB approach doesn't run that risk.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete individual cached web pages in Chrome by going into Settings > Site Settings > Storage. The pages are in descending size order. Chrome was using 1.1Gb until I deleted one page taking 389Gb.